# erlang mail server example

Tags: erlang, mail-server

I need simple erlang mail server example. I find erlmail, but i don't find how to setting it.

Where can i find it?

Thank you.

Comment: I googled for "erlmail" and I found three or four different projects. Which one are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is also gen_smtp on github https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation Wiki on github right where its hosted:
[Erlmail Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/erlmail/w/list)

Comment: Yes, but there no documentations how-to run it.